# How to limit Firefox RAM in Linux (Ubuntu) consumption without killing the process?

Tags: firefox, ram

For a very long time I can't find a solution to the problem of controlling the use of RAM by Firefox (and other programs) so that it works like the Firemin utility works in Windows, i.e. so that the process is not deleted when a certain threshold of RAM usage in the system is exceeded.

Is it possible to get clear instructions from specialists on how to configure this behavior for any program in Ubuntu?

There are different utilities (Earlyoom, Nohang, etc.), there is a cgroup, but as I understand it, everything eventually leads to the killing of the process and this is a rough decision, leading to an uncomfortable use of the same Firefox.

It is necessary to configure the restriction so that, for example, when the browser reaches the level of 700MB of RAM, this figure does not increase further and the browser continues its work correctly.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are experiencing? RAM is designed to be used and the OS will put it to good use intelligently.

Comment: Does [this resource](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-uses-too-much-memory-or-cpu-resources) from mozilla help at all as regards Firefox?